# How to check if a float array contains an exponential element

Tags: c#, arrays, exponential

How to find out if a double 2d array contains an exponential element?
For example

```
if(Array[i,j] == 3.402823E+38)
{
 //do something 
}
```

Basically I want to check if any of its elements ends with E+38.

Comment: E notation is nothing special; you can write any number using it. `1` is also `1E0`, `0.1E1`, `0.01E2`, and so on. That *specific* value is something special, though -- it looks like you want to test for `float.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jason N and @PMF
i found the answer here

```
if(myArray[col, line].ToString().EndsWith("E+38"))
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution works without converting to a string:

```
if(myArray[col, line] >= 1E+38 && myArray[col, line] < 1E+39)
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.Exists(array, element => Array.Exists(element,el=>el.EndsWith("E+38")));
```

is this ok ?

Comment: That would work if the array contained strings. But it contains numbers. And using `ToString()` here is probably not desirable

Comment: i tried that before but i need to check each element at a specific index, so if it EndsWith("E+38"))) , then its null for me!

Comment: oh, I thought you need to check all the elements in the array. If i, j is already defined, it will be fine